# Execute statement inside a common table expression in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

When I'm trying to use a execute statement inside a common table expression I'm getting error. I have given the code below. Please help me resolve the issue.

```
set @SQLStatement = 'select * from [Customers].[dbo].[Customer]';

with cte as 
(
exec (@SQLStatement)
),
cte1 as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select null)) AS RowNumber,* from cte
)
select * from cte1
```

---

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Get, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Get, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

here is my sp

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get] 
@StartIndex int, 
@EndIndex int, 
@SQLStatement varchar(max) 
AS 
BEGIN 



;with cte as 
(

exec (@SQLStatement)

),
cte1 as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select null)) AS RowNumber,* from cte
)
select * from cte1 where RowNumber between @StartIndex and @EndIndex 

END
```

Comment: You can't do that with a cte. A cte is an inline view not a container to hold whatever you want. From what you posted I don't see any need for dynamic sql. In your real situation you should look at using a temp table instead of a cte.

Comment: where did you get the idea that you can use dynamic sql inside a CTE?. Since this isn't really possible, you should explain what it is that you are trying to do as a whole, so we can maybe help with that

Comment: hi,im working on a stored procedure that will return desired number of rows from a select statement, say for an example your select statement returned million rows, i want only the rows from 1 to 2000.i created the following sp that will take select query as a parameter, startindex and endindex as other parameter all are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get] 
@StartIndex int, 
@EndIndex int, 
@WhereStmt varchar(max) 
AS 
BEGIN
execute('
;with cte as 
(
select * from customer '+ @WhereStmt+'
),
cte1 as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select null)) AS RowNumber,* from cte
)
select * from cte1 where RowNumber between '+@StartIndex+' and '+  @EndIndex+' 
')
END
```